# trying to redirect to login page in Angular only when logged out

Tags: angular, routes, angular-http-interceptors

My Angular application uses multiple modules. I managed to make the routing work, with the application normally redirecting to 'keeper/caregivers' but I have one issue: when I am in the root domain name, or localhost:4200, and I'm logged out, it should be redirecting me to the login page. Instead, it stays in the keeper/caregivers page, and displays an error that there is insufficient permission(see image below). I tried adding a redirect in my intercept function, but it seems like it never fires. Here is my code:
app-routing-module

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {RouterModule, Routes} from '@angular/router';
import {DefaultLayoutComponent} from './layout/default.layout.component';
import {AdminLayoutComponent} from './layout/admin.layout.component';
import {HhaLayoutComponent} from './layout/hha.layout.component';


const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'keeper', pathMatch: 'full' },

  {
    path: 'keeper',
    component: DefaultLayoutComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'caregivers',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      },

      {
        path: '',
        loadChildren: () =>
          import('./caregivers/caregivers.module').then(
            (m) => m.CaregiversModule,
          ),

      },
      // {
      //   path: 'caregivers',
      //   // redirectTo: 'caregivers',
      //   pathMatch: 'full'
      // },
      {
        path: 'transactions',
        loadChildren: () =>
          import('./transactions/transactions.module').then(
            (m) => m.TransactionsModule
          ),

      },
      {
        path: 'dashboard',
        loadChildren: () =>
          import('./dashboard/dashboard.module').then(
            (m) => m.DashboardModule
          ),

      },

      {
        path: 'payback-schedule',
        loadChildren: () =>
          import('./payback-schedule/payback-schedule.module').then(
            (m) => m.PaybackScheduleModule,
          ),

      },

      {
        path: 'caregivers',
        loadChildren: () =>
          import('./caregivers/caregivers.module').then(
            (m) => m.CaregiversModule,
          ),

      },
    ],
  },

  {
    path: 'admin',
    component: AdminLayoutComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'users',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      },

      {
        path: 'agencies',
        loadChildren: () =>
          import('./agencies/agencies.module').then(
            (m) => m.AgenciesModule
          ),
      },
      {
        path: 'users',
        loadChildren: () =>
          import('./admin/admin.module').then(
            (m) => m.AdminModule
          ),
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    path: 'provider-data',
    component: HhaLayoutComponent,
    children: [

      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'hha-caregivers',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      },
      {
        path: '',
        loadChildren: () =>
          import('./hha-caregivers/hha-caregivers.module').then(
            (m) => m.HhaCaregiversModule
          ),

      },
    ]
  },
  {
    path: 'auth',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('./auth/auth.module').then(
        (m) => m.AuthModule),
  },

];


@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {enableTracing: true})],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})

export class AppRoutingModule {
}
```

http-token-interceptor.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
  HttpRequest,
  HttpHandler,
  HttpEvent,
  HttpInterceptor, HttpErrorResponse, HttpResponse,
} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Observable, throwError} from 'rxjs';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import {catchError, switchMap, take, tap} from 'rxjs/operators';
import {Router} from "@angular/router";

@Injectable()
export class HttpTokenInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private auth: AngularFireAuth, private router: Router) {}

  intercept(
    request: HttpRequest<unknown>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<unknown>> {
    return this.auth.idToken.pipe(
      take(1),
      switchMap((token: any) => {
        if (token) {
          request = request.clone({
            setHeaders: {
              authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
            },
          });
        }
        return next.handle(request).pipe(tap(() => {},
          (err: any) => {
          if (err instanceof  HttpErrorResponse) {
            console.log(err.status);
            if (err.status !== 401) {
              return;
            }
            this.router.navigate(['auth/login']);

          }
          }));

      })
    );
  }
}
```

auth-routing.module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import {AuthPipe, customClaims} from "@angular/fire/auth-guard";
import {pipe} from "rxjs";
import {map} from "rxjs/operators";


const hasClaimPipe: (claim: string) => AuthPipe =
  (claim) => pipe(customClaims, map((claims) => {
    console.log(claims?.role);
    return claims?.role === claim
  }));

export const newAdminOnly = () => hasClaimPipe('admin')  ;
export const superAdminOnly = () => hasClaimPipe('superadmin');

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full' },
];



@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AuthRoutingModule { }
```

[image]
please let me know if there's any other code I should be posting

Answer (score 0):

As the error in he console shows, you are trying to read a prpoerty UID of a null object, but I can´t see in your code a UID prpoerty, maybe is in another file ?

Comment: this error doesn't show up in any routes, only when I'm logged out and typing root domain name or localhost:4200. I'm thinking the error is generated by firebase because the login is missing. I just need the page to redirect again to auth/login